# Animate new rows in ListView with a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, animation, cursor

Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this?  At the moment, a new row gets added to the database and I call requery().  I'd like any new rows to animate when they show up for the first time.  Many row additions will happen in the middle of the list, and not at the top or bottom.  I'd like these to animate somehow so the user can see them immediately.

I was thinking of perhaps having a hashmap (or some data structure) in my Adapter that holds the id of a particular row and a boolean stating whether or not it has been viewed.  In bindView, the boolean for the id of that row is checked and, if true, animates some flashing of some sort, and then updates the data structure.  Does this sound plausible?

Also, when the Cursor is requeried, I'd like to scroll the list to where the new row is.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can know its position without brute forcing through the list until I find it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know the answer to your question. Yes a HashMap which maps item ids to "already viewed" sounds like a good solution to this problem. If an item is new you can apply an animation to the item view when that item is rendered in bindView. You can also use the smoothScrollToPosition method in the ListView class to scroll to the first row that is new.

To populate the hashmap you would need to walk through all the items, you can also record the first item that is new at that time also.